# How to ground a plasma cutter

Tags: metal-cutting, welding

Just bought a Zeny 50 plasma cutter and I've never used one before. I will be using it outside in a paved area. Where should I ground the big alligator cable? Should I stick a copper pipe into the ground and clip it to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ground clamp should be connected to the (electrically conductive) workpiece that you're cutting.

- Make sure you're wearing all the proper safety equipment (gloves, eye protection, flame retardant clothes, etc.).
- Work in an area that prevents others from coming too close.
- Work in an area away from flammable materials.
- Make sure you are familiar with the operation of the equipment, and safety gear.
- Have a fire extinguisher nearby.
- Don't burn yourself or anybody else.

Comment: I see. What threw me off was that most videos did not do this but used a metal table. I'm assuming you can just connect it to the metal table and cut the piece on top of it?

Comment: @swinefeaster Yes, that's correct. If you're working on a conductive surface, you can simply ground to the surface.